# Change Root in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

right now my active_admin gem in Rails has a default url of

www.home.com/admin

however the active admin resides in

www.home.com/group/admin

How can I make it so that every link in active admin will route to /group/admin/[next link]

I tried Gmat's solution below and this is what happened:

> new_group_admin_user_session GET           /group/admin/login(.:format) 
>   active_admin/devise/sessions#new
>               group_admin_user_session POST       /group/admin/login(.:format)
>   active_admin/devise/sessions#create
>       destroy_group_admin_user_session DELETE|GET /group/admin/logout(.:format)
>   active_admin/devise/sessions#destroy
>              group_admin_user_password POST       /group/admin/password(.:format)
>   active_admin/devise/passwords#create
>          new_group_admin_user_password GET        /group/admin/password/new(.:format)
>   active_admin/devise/passwords#new
>         edit_group_admin_user_password GET        /group/admin/password/edit(.:format)
>   active_admin/devise/passwords#edit
>                                              PUT        /group/admin/password(.:format)
>   active_admin/devise/passwords#update
>                       group_admin_root            /group/admin(.:format)                          group/admin/dashboard#index
>                             group_root            /group(.:format)                                group/dashboard#index
>         batch_action_group_admin_leads POST       /group/admin/leads/batch_action(.:format)
>   group/admin/leads#batch_action
>                      group_admin_leads GET        /group/admin/leads(.:format)
>   group/admin/leads#index
>                                              POST       /group/admin/leads(.:format)
>   group/admin/leads#create
>                   new_group_admin_lead GET        /group/admin/leads/new(.:format)                group/admin/leads#new
>                  edit_group_admin_lead GET        /group/admin/leads/:id/edit(.:format)           group/admin/leads#edit
>                       group_admin_lead GET        /group/admin/leads/:id(.:format)                group/admin/leads#show
>                                              PUT        /group/admin/leads/:id(.:format)
>   group/admin/leads#update
>                                              DELETE     /group/admin/leads/:id(.:format)
>   capstonemlg/admin/leads#destroy
>                  group_admin_dashboard            /group/admin/dashboard(.:format)
>   group/admin/dashboard#index

I apologize for the formatting. The point is that all the links www.home.com/group/[anything] is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# config/routes.rb
namespace :group do
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
end
```

Comment: This does seem to change the route in rake routes. However the link www.home.com/group/admin becomes broken. I edited the question to include the rake routes output

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to customize the ActiveAdmin namespace as well.

http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html

`ActiveAdmin.register Post, :namespace => "groups/admin"`

Comment: where do I do this? In the config/initializer/active_admin.rb file?

Comment: in the app/admin/resource.rb , you need to tell the ActiveAdmin the name space there (AFAIK, there might be a way better way to do this, but I haven't found it)

Comment: What you did seems to make sense, but it leads back to my assets:precompile to show:   `Invalid route name: 'group/admin_root'`

Comment: You probably need @gmats namespace :group as well, in order to make the router/assets happy

Comment: the just seems to result in `Invalid route name: 'group/group/admin_root'

Comment: hmm not really sure, was kinda guessing.